# 98 Ford Explorer FOB reprogramming not working

Tags: ford, keyless-entry, un105

I just bought a Ford Explorer key fob off of Amazon and it came with instructions as to how to reprogram my car. Having follored this, as well as reading the manual and various posts online, my car fails to accept it. Here is what I mean:

The instructions say to insert the key into the ignition and turn from off (where the key is able to be inserted and removed) to on (2 clicks beyond off) 8 times, then on the 8th time to leave the key in the on position. If done correctly doors are supposed to cycle locked - unlocked. My Doors do not. I sat in my car for a good 30 mins turning it on and off to no avail. My car did come with lojack, but I disabled it.

Any ideas as to how to reprogram my car? I have the two keys and 2 original fobs (which are giving out).

Comment: Some auto parts stores (in my case AutoZone) have a display that tests key fobs. You point yours at it and the display lights if it works. Since yours is of unknown reliability verify that it works.

Comment: Its not even the key FOB right now, I cant get my car into the program mode and that is what i need help with

Comment: Positive. its even in my manual.

Comment: If so equipped, disable the autolamp function prior to cycling key.

Answer (score 2):

Looking online, the only difference I see as to what you are doing and what is suggested is to turn the key eight times **within 10 seconds**. It may be you are not getting all of the key turns in within the allotted time. For the entire sequence, the following steps are applicable (so others know when looking):

1. Have all transmitters available before starting, as even programmed remotes will need to be done again.
2. Place key in the ignition and rapidly turn from OFF to ON positions eight (8) times within 10 seconds finishing in ON position. Do not engage starter.
3. If doors do not automatically lock/unlock, repeat step 2.
4. Press one button on every transmitter.
5. Turn ignition to LOCK and remove key.
6. Check the operation of all transmitters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Close all doors then open drivers door then press  the UNLOCK Button on drivers door leave door open then insert key then off to on 8times without starting on 8th time leave key on you only have 10 seconds to do this door locks will run  to confirm pairing turn key off doors will lock to confirm pairing YOU DONE  don't forget to activate by pressing the function I and panic at the same time panic is the horn

Comment: Welcome to the site ... could you do us a favor and spread this out into a step-by-step, putting some punctuation into the mix so we can all understand what you're trying to say? As it reads, it's below poor quality, even though the information may be correct.